# Inter-plugin configuration and Maven 3

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin, swig

I have several Maven2 projects which use the NAR and SWIG plugins to build mixed Java, C & C++ projects. The SWIG plugin configures the NAR plugin dynamically like so:

```
Plugin narPlugin = (Plugin) project.getBuild().getPluginsAsMap()
            .get("org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-nar-plugin");
Xpp3Dom narConfig = new Xpp3Dom("configuration");
.
.
.
narPlugin.setConfiguration(narConfig);
```

Now I would like to upgrade to Maven3. The configuration of the NAR plugin seems to work from the SWIG plugin's perspective. That is, subsequent calls to

```
narPlugin.getConfiguration()
```

show the dynamic configuration, but when the NAR plugin executes it has it has no configuration unless explicitly added in the pom.

I remember reading somewhere that Maven3 has reduced the scope of configuration via the above method. Is that what's going on? How do I configure Maven3 to allow this kind of inter-plugin configuration?

For reference here is the pom

```
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>ral</groupId>
   <artifactId>jtpk-${os.arch}</artifactId>
   <packaging>nar</packaging>
   <version>2.3-1</version>
   <name>jTPK - JNI wrapped astrometric library</name>
   <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

   <dependencies></dependencies>
   <build>
      <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-swig-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-7</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
               <!-- Version of swig to use -->
               <version>3.0.2-1</version>
               <source>swig_tpk.swg</source>
               <cpp>true</cpp>
               <packageName>org.lcogt.jTPK.swig</packageName>
               <!-- Nar config -->
               <includePaths>
                  <includePath>src/main/cpp/lco</includePath>
               </includePaths>
               <excludes>
                  <exclude>**/WinClock.cpp</exclude>
               </excludes>
               <compilerOptions>
                  <option>-DTIXML_USE_STL=1</option>
               </compilerOptions>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>generate</goal>
                  </goals>
               </execution>
            </executions>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-nar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1-5</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration></configuration>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>nar-download</goal>
                     <goal>nar-unpack</goal>
                  </goals>
               </execution>
            </executions>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
</project>
```

Comment: First i would suggest to check the up-to-date site for nar-maven-plugin http://maven-nar.github.io/. The configuration of plugins is done in pom via pluginManagement. May be i misunderstand your question? Can you eleborate a little bit more what you mean?

Comment: I see the same problem with the master branch of nar-maven-plugin. Although I generally use my own fork of maven-nar-plugin which dates from a few years ago when it was hard to get fixes into the plugin.

Comment: The SWIG plugin builds a configuration for the NAR plugin at runtime and uses setConfiguration() on the NAR plugin returned from MavenProject.getBuild().getPluginsAsMap() to pass the configuration from one plugin to the next. This works fine under Maven2. In Maven3 the NAR plugin seems to have amnesia about the setConfiguration() and only sees configuration specified in the pom.